# Azure: access ServiceConfiguration.cscfg from startup.cmd?

Tags: azure

Does anyone know if it is possible to access the ServiceConfiguration.cscfg from the startup.cmd of a role?

Is the ServiceConfiguration.cscfg placed any where on the physical VM of the role?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a startup script that fires a powershell script:

```
powershell.exe Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
powershell.exe .\mypsscript.ps1 >> ..\startup-tasks-log.txt 2>>..\startup-tasks-error-log.txt
```

Then, in the PowerShell script, you can easily access the RoleEnvironment class (and config values as well):

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime")

$roleInstanceId = [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment]::CurrentRoleInstance.Id
$appTitle = [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment]::GetConfigurationSettingValue("AppTitle")
```

etc.

Comment: I know this answer is old but could someone help me use it? how do you bring the powershell stuff into the startup script?

Comment: You should call this from a batch file, as described here: http://blog.smarx.com/posts/windows-azure-startup-tasks-tips-tricks-and-gotchas